# Workbench 2 and 3 Documentation HTML Build Fails (Output file test failed)

Tags: documentation, workbench, html

In Wolfram Workbench it used to be possible to generate HTML Documentation pages. Now when I build, using Mathematica 10.4+ and Workbench 2 or 3 on Windows 8.1, the HTML build fails (the notebook documentation build still works).

The error I receive in the `AntLog` is:
`*** Output file test failed ***`. Which means that the HTML files are not Exported.

Tracing a bit further in `ExportDocumentation` I found the function `Transmogrify`, which should have exported the HTML but does not.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me: Mathematica 11.0.1, MacOS 10.12, Wolfram Workbench 10.1.755, Eclipse Neon.1 Release (4.6.1).

Comment: @ChrisK, Thanks for checking. I will try the Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Partial Solution

Wolfram Workbench 2 and 3 are not able to launch the front end (Mathematica 10+) to create the final HTML. The solution is to use the new (Eclipse-plugin) version, downloadable from: https://www.wolfram.com/workbench/. Which is also free when you have purchased a Mathematica license.

**Some issues with the HTML**

*edit:* I took the time to document the steps bellow in more detail [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134069/workbench-eclipse-version-html-documentation-build-html-issues).

I encountered some issues with the generated HTML (my best guess is that the HTML for local viewing, as Wolfram is calling it, is not updated). Not sure if I fixed this in the right place, so please if you have a better solution let me know. These fixes should be done in the

- in fonts.css (either in the minimal or standard folder) the font SourceSansPro-Semibold.woff seems to have an incorrect path replace all: `/fonts/sourcesanspro/v8/fonts/SourceSansPro` with `/fonts/sourcesanspro/v8/SourceSansPro`
- the folder: `images/mathematicaIncludes` does not seem to be copied for local viewing.
- It is not possible to click to code to copy (like on the Mathematica site). Change the jquery version to 1.7.2 (already in the export), and add the clipboards.js from Wolfram: `http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/javascript/clipboard.js`, The styling can be fixed by: `http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/css/clipboard.css`. Don't forget to also include the two images: `http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/images/clipboard@2x.png` and `http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/images/check-mark@2x.png`
- The collapsed pages (like Scope and options) do not show the code sniplets but the text `Click code to copy`. Apparently the sub-pages.js is outdated, i looked up which they used on their site: http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/javascript/sub-pages.js. This fixes the problem.
- Links on the top right corner (see also) relative path is not correct, leading to a dead page.

Comment: Hi @Frank did you ever get this to work? I'm on workbench eclipse plugin 10.1.757 and still see every single issue you mention and more...

Comment: @M.R. yes it worked fine. You can see that it worked at: http://www.lieanalysis.nl/documentation/ . I geuss i will be updating this answer soon with some new insights. If you encounter any difficulties I be happy to help.

Comment: @M.R. Not that the link in previous comment is a work in progress ;)

Comment: I checked out your site, very nice. I would love to know how you overcame all the issues in the html build process and maybe wrap it into a git repo. Perhaps we can have a chat session if you have a free moment. I added pictures of the problems I see while exporting below.

Comment: How do you "change the version of jquery" btw?

Comment: @user5601 You have to alter the html <script> tag which imports jquery. So you end up with: `<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/jquery/core/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>`. with the `src` the relative path to the jquery.js. To debug these kind of things you need some html/js skills.

Comment: @M.R. Let me start by updating my answer, let's take it from there.

Comment: @M.R. Lets continue to solve the HTML problems in a seperate post. As this is nog longer related to the original question. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134069/workbench-html-documentation-build-html-issues

Comment: Ok, sounds good. What about a chat/messaging session?

Comment: @M.R. Sure, what do you suggest? I might be unavailable the next week as I have mandatory leave ;).

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but an extended comment. I'm on macos 10.12.1 with v11.0.1 and I'm using this version of the eclipse (for java developers) wolfram plugin:

[image]

I wanted to put up ***pictures of all the glitches from the html export*** process:

- Corrupted input cells:

  [image]
- Corrupted input and output cells:

  [image]
- Missing input cells:

  [image]
- Arrows not formatting:

  [image]
- Broken extended examples sections:

  [image]

---

- Frank Martin was able to get this click to copy button working:

  [image]

Comment: I wonder if wolfram has a newer version of DocumentationBuild/Tools, Transmogrify, and html.xml and hasn't released it?

Comment: The html.xml build script references MMA6: `<property name="mathExe" value="C:\\Program\ Files\\Wolfram\ Research\\Mathematica\\6.0\\MathKernel.exe"/>` There must be a new version somewhere no?

Comment: Some of these issues are related to the javascript, ill update this post early next year.