# How to convert documentation into web-site like Wolfram's Documentation?

Tags: export, notebooks, html

I can build documentation notebooks but I'd like them to be deployed just like Mathematica's internal notebooks are on  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/.

Crucially, I would like the open/close toggle behavior and copy-on-click behavior preserved.

Comment: Related: ([128597](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128597/workbench-3-generate-html-documentation-fails))

Comment: `I would like the open/close toggle behavior and copy-on-click behavior preserved`  I think the copy-on-click is absolutely terrible idea made by WRI. I complained about it [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/843795?p_p_auth=pkMn7VWh) The reason is simple. one now no longer can copy just part of the command shown. Many times one might want to copy only part of the command, say an option name, or such, and not the whole thing. Now this is not possible. This is another idea where fashion won over functionality and practical use.  WRI should remove this feature from the help pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to switch to an IDE, the Eclipse-based Wolfram Workbench plugin [Eclipse-based Wolfram Workbench plugin](http://www.wolfram.com/workbench/) has their automated HTML generator as part of the package.

Comment: I find that the HTML generator doesn't do a very good job making the conversion.

Comment: I'd like it to look/act/feel the same their official documentation site, is that what will happen?

Comment: @M.R. Links are broken, and open/close section toggles are sometimes broken.

Comment: Interesting and good to know. I haven't played with it enough to actually see how well it works.