# Workbench (Eclipse version) HTML Documentation Build HTML issues

Tags: documentation, workbench, html

### Description

The HTML generated for local viewing by Workbench (Eclipse plugin version 10.1.757) has some issues before they can be published. This post is in continuation of the [original question about HTML Build](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128597/workbench-2-and-3-documentation-html-build-fails-output-file-test-failed)

## Issues

1. CSS fonts not found
2. Some images are missing
3. It is not possible to copy code from the webpage
4. The content of the collapsed content is empty

   - In collapsed pages the expressions are not rendered but shown as `Click code to copy`
5. Quicklinks on the top right corner have an incorrect path

Comment: I tremble with excitement....

Comment: @QuantumDot You no longer have to wait, enjoy the ride ;')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update  10-2017:** I noticed that they released an update of these tools, so some of these steps are outdated. I adjusted this answer to the newest 
release of Workbench 10.1.822. It has become somewhat easier, therefore I also created an automated script for my usecase. Feel free to use it:

```
(* Directory containing html folder, e.g. C:/project/build/projectname-HTML/html *)
$htmlDirectory = "path/to/html/folder";

(*1.1 Copy Dependencies to Main Folder*)
localFiles = FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,"standard"}]
folders = FileNames["*",localFiles] 
CopyDirectory[#,
   FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,Last[FileNameSplit[#]]}]]&/@folders;

(*1.2 Fix HTML Links and Scripts*)
htmlFiles = FileNames["*.html",{
    FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,"ref"}],
     FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,"guide"}],
     FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,"tutorial"}]
}]

Do[
  Block[{source},
    source = Import[file,"Source"];

    (* Insert jQuery *)
    source = StringReplace[source,
        "<script src=\"/webMathematica/Resources/Documentation/English/javascript/reference.js\"></script>"->
        "
            <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"../css/clipboard.css\" />
            <script src=\"../javascript/jquery/core/1.7.2/jquery.min.js\"></script>
            <script src=\"../javascript/reference.js\"></script>
        "
    ];

    (* fix relative paths *)
    source = StringReplace[source, {
        "/webMathematica/Resources/Documentation/English/"->"../",
        "/2013/javascript/"->"../javascript/"
    }];

    (* fix bullet.gif *)
    source = StringReplace[source,"../images/mathematicaImages/bullet.gif"->"../images/bullet-greysq.gif"];

    (* save *)
    Export[file,source,"Text"];
],{file,htmlFiles}]

(*2.2 Adjust the CSS*)
cssFontFile = FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,"css","fonts.css"}]
css = Import[cssFontFile,"Text"];
css = StringReplace[css,"/fonts/sourcesanspro/v8/fonts/"->"/fonts/sourcesanspro/v8/"];


Export[cssFontFile,css,"Text"]

(*3. Fix Missing Content in Collapsed Containers*)


fasterPageLoadFile = FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,"javascript","faster-page-load.js"}]
js = Import[fasterPageLoadFile,"Text"];
js = StringReplace[js,"baselang.slice(0,-3)"->"baselang"];


Export[fasterPageLoadFile,js,"Text"]

(*4. Fix Click to Copy Cells*)
subpagesFile = FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,"javascript","sub-pages.js"}];
subpagesFile//FileExistsQ
DeleteFile[subpagesFile]


Export[subpagesFile, Uncompress["1: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"],"Text"]

(*5. Fix Code Copying from Web Page*)
clipboardJs = FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,"javascript","clipboard.en.js"}];
clipboardJsNew = FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,"javascript","clipboard.js"}];
RenameFile[clipboardJs,clipboardJsNew]

clipboardCss = FileNameJoin[{$htmlDirectory,"css","clipboard.css"}]
css = Import[clipboardCss,"Text"];
css = StringReplace[css,"/webMathematica/Resources/Documentation/English/images/"->"../images/"];
Export[clipboardCss,css,"Text"]
```

All the fixes below are post-build, it would be better to modify the DocumentationTools so that we don't have to do these steps each time we want to generate the HTML (although keep in mind that these files might be overwritten in case of an update). Also, the steps below should be the same in case of a Windows machine.

---

## 1. Incorrect `script` and `link` paths

If you have managed to build the HTML the first thing you encounter that the HTML files are missing their dependencies as we only see plain HTML, see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s543Cm.png).
[image: Only plain HTML is rendered when we open the HTML files]

### 1.1 Dependency Locations

The build did store these dependencies in the build folder, just not in the location that the HTML-file specifies. There are two folders which you can use: the `html/standard` and `html/minimal` folder. I recommend using the `html/standard` folder as you will be able to adjust the files to your needs. I recommend pasting all contents of `html/standard` to `html/`.

### 1.2 Inspect/Fix Paths in the HTML-file

If we open a HTML file we see that the `link` and `script`-tag path do not point towards this folder, see image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9D8kv.png). [image: dependencies have the wrong paths] We also note that the jquery script is not referenced at all so we need to add jquery before the other `script` tags, see figure [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPs6R.png).[image: dependencies have the correct path]

### 1.3 Examine

Now, if we open the HTML-files, it looks somewhat like the documentation pages we are used to. Also you should be able to open and collapse sections (even though its content might be absent), see figure [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8yfa.png).
[image: The HTML documentation pages look like the original documentation pages]

---

## 2 Fix Missing CSS fonts

If we inspect the HTML with the developer tools -and look in the console- we see a bunch of errors regarding missing fonts, see image [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTBZb.png). [image: Error messages regarding missing fonts]

### 2.1 Font Locations

The fonts that are missing are in the build folder, but somehow the path is again incorrect. The fonts that are missing are located in:
`/html/fonts/sourcesanspro/v8/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf`

### 2.2 Adjust the CSS

To fix this we adjust the `html/css/fonts.css`, with the following replacement: 
replace `/fonts/sourcesanspro/v8/fonts/` with `/fonts/sourcesanspro/v8/`, see figure [7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwLuW.png). [image: Modifying the font path in the CSS]

---

## 3 Fix Missing Content in Collapsed Containers

When you try to expand a collapsed item, e.g. the scope section, no content is shown. And with the DeveloperTools the following error is dispatched, see figure [8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBUsY.png). [image: Content is missing in the collapsed pages]

The links do not exist, they seem to have cut the filename. For this you need to edit file `/html/standard/javascript/faster-page-load.js`. In which you need to remove `.slice(0,-3)` from line 2, see figure [9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wa3u.png). [image: Remove the slice from this function]

*Note: if you are looking at the webpages on your local machine, make sure you use chrome and using the flag "--allow-file-access-from-files"*

---

## 4 Fix *Click to Copy* Cells

Sometimes, not exactly sure when, the input cells show *Click to Copy* instead of their actual input, the *Click to Copy* should be the alternate text if no image can be found. This also fixes the problem when the collapsed pages do not open at all.
[image: Weird behaviour in collapsable pages]
To fix this you will need to update the files 
`/html/javascript/sub-pages.js`, I copied them from the [Wolfram site itself](http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/javascript/sub-pages.js).

*Note: In previous versions of the DocumentationTools you also needed to add `image-swap.js` to the javascript folder, download it from here [wolfram site itself](http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/javascript/image-swap.js)*.

---

## 5 Fix Code Copying from Web Page

It would be nice if you can copy code from the website and paste it directly into Mathematica just as the official Mathematica site. A few things need to be updated.

*Note: In previous versions of Documentation Tools you needed to update the jQuery version, this is no longer needed*

### 5.1 Rename `clipboard.en.js` to `clipboard.js`

*Note: In previous versions of DocumentationTools you had to download this file from their [website](http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/javascript/clipboard.js) and add it to your Javascript files*

You need to rename `/html/javascript/clipboard.en.js` to `/html/javascript/clipboard.js`. (Assuming you want the english version, and no multi-language support).

### 5.2 Edit and Add clipboard.css

*Note: In previous versions of DocumentationTools you had to download this file from their [website](http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/css/clipboard.css) and add it to you css files*

Add the following line to your HTML files:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/clipboard.css" />`

Replace the following in `html/css/clipboard.css`:
replace `/webMathematica/Resources/Documentation/English/images/` with `../images/`.

*Note: In previous versions of DocumentationTools you had to download the two images [image1](http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/images/clipboard@2x.png) and [image2](http://reference.wolfram.com/2013/images/check-mark@2x.png) and store them in `html/images/`*

Comment: One font fix to add: a new version of `"reference-special-styles"` needs to be downloaded

Comment: Your code is a lifesaver. Thank you so much!