# Problem with links when using Workbench (Eclipse version) HTML Documentation Build

Tags: documentation, workbench, html

I am building a package documentation with eclipse workbench. I have used the Mathematica code in the following link [Workbench (Eclipse version) HTML Documentation Build HTML issues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134069/workbench-eclipse-version-html-documentation-build-html-issues/208477#208477) to fix some problems with the HTML files built. But there is still a problem with the links corresponding to the symbols in each page. I obtained for example the following code:

```
> <p class="singleFunction"><a name="1463276848"></a><span
> class="IFSans"><a href="FIXME">ttr</a></span> <span
> class="dash">&mdash;</span> Triple point temperature</p>
```

So there is systematically a "FIXME" in href instead of the correct path. How I can fix this with a program instead of doeing it manually in each file?

There is also some more problems: for example all the Mathematica codes in the sub-menu Options does not appear in the HTML version?

Thank you