# Convert Doc Notebook to HTML

Tags: documentation, html

Is there any built-in utility to convert a documentation notebook to the type of page that's on the Wolfram website, e.g. the web version of [`FormFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormFunction.html) from the desktop version?

I want to be able to set up my documentation on the web, just for interest sake, and that would save me some time.

Comment: I believe [Wolfram Workbench](http://www.wolfram.com/workbench/?source=footer) has the necessary tools to generate the HTML files.  But, I've never had any luck generating fully functional and good looking HTML files.

Comment: @QuantumDot that's good to know. Unfortunately I am not a Workbench user but maybe I can deconstruct their tools. When you say you've never had luck what sort of issues have you run into? It might also be worth my time to just write the functions myself.

Comment: I run into the issues described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128597/workbench-2-and-3-documentation-html-build-fails-output-file-test-failed) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134069/workbench-eclipse-version-html-documentation-build-html-issues).